# Can I Photo montage from a series of other photos?

Tags: python, uv-image-editor

I am trying to build a floating collage effect. That is a series of images hanging in space or attached to another surface, that when seen from a distance coalesce into a single image. But when viewed close up reveal each component.

I would need to asses properties of image textures on 'plane' objects and build them into a master image. Could Blender achieve this manipulation of a set? i.e. interrogate images-assign properties, allocate to arrangement

Can I use python to asses average values and hues of a series of images to assign them as substitute pixels of another larger image?

- I guess I would have to sample the master image to be reproduced
  assigning a grid of values/hues.
- Then sample a set of 'pixel' images
  for their value/hue.
- Then assign them to the grid assuming they fall    within acceptable
  boundary per pixel?
- Then attach 'pixel' images to hooks at master image grid points.

I could then animate the hooks so that they move away or towards their resting position.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/cinemast/OpenMosaic

Comment: @3pointedit, at first glance this question does not seem to be about Blender. Please make the connection to Blender more explicit.

Comment: Ok I will try to be more explicit in function. Thanks

Comment: @batFINGER that looks pretty close to what I was looking for however I wanted to be able to arrange each 'pixel' image as an object in 3D space. I will amend my OP.

Comment: And it's in python 2.x .. (there are conversion scripts) it does though have the code to analyze the tile images, and place them in folders.  Import image as planes can be used to import.  Then alter output code to  a data file  that can be imported into blender. Your eg has differing size images, would need to do something like http://www.drdobbs.com/database/the-maximal-rectangle-problem/184410529.   I did look into this a while back, (would make a great sound animation)  but put it in the too hard basket... then again.. message me via BA if you are keen to put something together.

Comment: Note even using the final mosaic output and then just offset (crop) to each tile based on data would be another way to go.

Comment: Hmm, thats not a bad idea. I could always substitute the hero 'pixel' images that I want to zoom into.